# How do I see a php.ini parameter via code?

Tags: php

I'm developing an app in `php` and want to see how is set the `memory_limit`(or any other) parameter on `php.ini` via code.

It's possible?

Comment: `phpinfo()` an that server might be a good bet (i am assuming that the server is a third partuy affair!)

Comment: All answers are right, but I accepted the first right answer, thank you all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ini_get().

More information can be found at :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get.php

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can: see [ini_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.ini-get.php).

```
$value = ini_get('memory_limit');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ini_set() function to set memory_limit or ini_get() to get the memory_limit  in PHP.

**Example:**

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
ini_get('memory_limit');
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with what he asks. He doesn't want to increase memory, but he wants to know what is the memory limit.

Comment: how is set the memory_limit.
Set or increase two things same idea

Answer (score 0):

Even better, [`ini_get_all([ string $extension [, bool $details = true ]]);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-get-all.php)